# after sorting gridview rowcommand not firing when clicking button in datarow

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is binded to a datasource like this:

```
var beerlist = (from b in ctx.beers
select new
                        {
                            id = b.beerid,
                            b.brand,
                            b.kind,
                            etc...       }).ToList();
        BeerListGridView.DataSource = beerlist;
        DataBind();
```

i do this in the page_load event with: if (!IsPostBack).

now i add buttons in the onrowdatabound event like this:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        String beerid = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
        int columncount = e.Row.Cells.Count;

        TableCell MyCell = new TableCell();
        Button EditButton = new Button();
        EditButton.ID = beerid;
        EditButton.Text = "Edit";
        EditButton.CommandName = "EditButton_Click";
        EditButton.CommandArgument = beerid;
        MyCell.Controls.Add(EditButton);
        MyCell2.Controls.Add(InfoButton);
        e.Row.Cells.AddAt(columncount, MyCell);
        e.Row.Cells.AddAt(columncount + 1, MyCell2);
```

the rowcommand event looks like this:

```
if (e.CommandName != "Sort")
    {
        Session["beerid"] = e.CommandArgument;
        if (e.CommandName == "EditButton_Click")
        {
            Response.Redirect("EditBeer.aspx");
        }
        else if (e.CommandName == "InfoButton_Click")
        {
            Response.Redirect("ViewRatingsRemarks.aspx");
        }
    }
```

in the sorting event i do the following:

```
if (e.SortExpression == "brand")
    {
        if (Session["brandsortorder"] == null)
        {
            var beerlist = (from b in ctx.beers
                            orderby b.brand
                            select new
                            {
                                id = b.beerid,
                                b.brand,
                                b.kind,
                                etc...          }).ToList();
            BeerListGridView.DataSource = beerlist;
            DataBind();
            Session["brandsortorder"] = "DESC";
        }
        else if  etc..
```

when i click the edit button al the buttons disappear an i am left with the datagridview without the buttons.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Rather than adding the content when the data is bound, just include it in the template of the row; it will make your life *much* easier.

Comment: yess I have seen that but i could not get it to work??? can you give an example?

Comment: The documentation for `GridView` is full of examples on how to do it, and there are thousands more examples all over the web.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the buttons are disappearing is that you're binding (again) your datagrid and the buttons are not being re-created.

This article should get you started quickly on GridView with templates and editing.

[CodeProject - Editable Gridview](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23471/Editable-GridView-in-ASP-NET)

Answer (score 0):

Thanx for the advice, i did the following:
added boundfields to gridview and set autogeneratecolumns of gridview to false:

```
<asp:GridView ID="BeerListGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="BeerListGridView_RowCommand" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="BeerListGridView_Sorting" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" SortExpression="id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="brand" HeaderText="brand" SortExpression="brand" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="kind" HeaderText="kind" SortExpression="kind" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="alcperc" HeaderText="alcperc" SortExpression="alcperc" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="taste" HeaderText="taste" SortExpression="taste" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="color" HeaderText="color" SortExpression="color" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="land" HeaderText="land" SortExpression="land" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="brewery" HeaderText="brewery" SortExpression="brewery" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="addedby" HeaderText="addedby" SortExpression="addedby" />
            <asp:TemplateField><ItemTemplate><asp:Button Text="edit" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" /></ItemTemplate></asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
```

as you can see at the end i added the column with the edit buttons and filled in commandname and commandargument. It works!!! (onrowdatabound is not neccesary anymore...)